# How to assign property value with environment variable in docker file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I am working on docker file with springboot. This line in docker file

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dbootstrap.servers=$DB_PATH","org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

when I run `"docker run -p 9000:9000 -e DB_PATH=newvalue imaginename"`

I want bootstrap.servers to take value of variable $DB_PATH, however, it will not work and only takes variable name "$DB_PATH"

Or how can i let bootstrap.servers take variables in docker container ?
please help.

Thanks

Comment: Use the shell form, `ENTRYPOINT java -Dbootstrap.servers=$DB_PATH ...`; this will invoke a shell that will do the variable expansion.

Comment: @DavidMaze . thanks you mean like this ? ENTRYPOINT java -Dbootstrap.servers=$DB_PATH org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Comment: it works. you saved my date. thank you so much...........!!!!!!!!!!!!